# apache mod-rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ([0-9a-zA-Z_\-]+)(|\.html|\.php)$ page.php
```

this is the rule is .htacess.
what I want is if file is not found then redirect to page.php.
for example if url people.php ,people.html is not found then redirect to page.php.

because I also want those filenames without .php like people direct to people.php first. then check file exist or not, if not redirect to page.php.
how do I add one rule to make people redirect to people.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These rules should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

# if there is no . in request then append .php
# it is important to make [L] as last rule here
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.php [L]

# 404 handling for files that don't exist
# NC is for ignore case comparison
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^[^.]+\.(html|php)$ /page.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: why make the first as the last rule, it should check if the filename doesn't include .php then append .php at the end of filename, then check it is exist or not, if not exist then redirect to page.php. also all the reg expression must not include any othe file extenstion like .js .css .jpg etc

Comment: Both the rules will still execute one after another, `L` flag won't interrupt in that. `[L]` flag above will just stop 2nd rule to fire  for the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.` condition.

Answer (score 1):

See if this does what you're looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(?:.+/)?([^/.]+)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule \.(?:html|php)$ page.php
```

Comment: it works perfertly, could you please explain to how it works?

Comment: @fuminlu Certainly!

**`RewriteRule ^(?:.+/)?([^/.]+)$ $1.php`**
_`(?:)` - No backreference is assigned to this group._

`^(?:.+/)?` - Matches everything up to the last slash, if there is one.
`([^/.]+)$` - Matches a filename a without an extension.

The slashes are there so it will work in subfolders as well.

**`RewriteRule \.(?:html|php)$ page.php`**
_Note: I changed this slightly in my answer to make it simpler._
_`\.` - Matches a dot._
_`(?:)` - Could also just be `()`._

As long as the file/folder doesn't exist, the pattern matches if the path ends in .html or .php.

Comment: Sure thing! I don't know if that explanation actually helped a lot or not, though. I'm new to Stack Overflow and didn't realize comments don't allow new lines, so it got a bit jumbled.

Tomorrow maybe I'll edit my answer to include a better explanation for you. In the meantime, this is a good site to learn the basics of regular expressions, if you're interested (assuming you don't already know regular expressions well): http://www.regular-expressions.info/